# Can't change button's height on bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I decided to upload my website's bootstrap version to bootstrap 4. After the update, I got a lot of issues, because bootstrap changed a lot with the new version and I basically had to rewrite most of the code on my website. I also had to rewrite navbar, because of a lot of new cool classes they added.

The navbar works perfectly, but there are some issues related to the height. I manage to change the height of the navbar, but the child elements are using the full height of the navbar and I don't like it. For example, i have this code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-sm bg-custom">
          <div class="container no gutters">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav">
              <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Link1</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
              </ul>
              <ul class="navbar-nav social list-inline">
                <a class="butn py-1" href="#">Link1</a>
                <div class="align justify-content-center">
                  <a class="list-inline-item" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a class="list-inline-item" href="#services"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a class="list-inline-item" href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

As you can see I use 2 different nav's on the same line, I like the first one, but with the second one there's also a button, which is taking the full height of the navbar and I can't seem to change it.

Live version here: http://tanely.anweb.ee

I may have missed something from the docs but it seems that the flexbox won't let me change the height like I want to. I want that the button wouldn't use parent height, instead, it should use the height of the element, in this case, it's element a with a class of butn.

I tried to set different heights, change padding, margin, tried to mess with the flexbox properties(for parents too) etc, but still, none of it is helping me.

I thought maybe some of you can check it out and educate me a little.

Answer (score 1):

The default height for flex items in a flex parent is "stretch," so that's what you're seeing. But your HTML is invalid. Only an `li` can be a direct child of a `ul`. If you wrap that `a` in an `li`, that will fix some of the invalid HTML, and then the `li` will "stretch" and the `a` inside it will be it's natural height.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav social list-inline">
  <li><a class="butn py-1" href="#">Link1</a></li>
  ...
```

Comment: Okay, but can I change that flex stretch?

Comment: @drpzz not really. You can overwrite the "stretch" behavior by specifying a height on the button, that works fine. You just can't let the button grow to it's natural height based on content when it's a flex child like that. You either let it "stretch" or you specify a height.